# display : table not take the dynamic height take their children height

Tags: css, height, display

I have 3 div elements, one is the parent and other two are children:

```
<div id="table">
  <div id="first"> dinesh </div>
  <div id="second"> pathak </div>
</div>

and their css are:

        #table {
          display: table;
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px; 
          margin: 0;
          border: 5px solid blue;
          padding: 5px;
        }

        #first {
          display: table-cell;
          border: 3px solid red;
          margin: 2px;
          width: 50px;
          height: 200px;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        #second {
          display: table-cell;
          border: 3px solid red;
          margin: 2px;
          width: 50px;
          height: 200px;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
```

I am giving the #table div the height of element height #first, and #second has the height that is greater than its parent. But I want that the inner div to be visible only if their parent height and the rest are hidden. But the parent is taking the height of its children.

Comment: The height is the same for all three elements

Comment: @Mark parent div has the client height and inner div have height greater than its parent.

Comment: I have to restrict them into its parent height.

Comment: I see. Does the display have to be table, or can you use something else?

Comment: @Mark sir It should be table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Overflow:hidden` only works on block-level elements, hence it not working with `display: table`. To fix this, you can use `position: absolute` on your inner elements and `position: relative` on the parent div.

Hope this helps!

```css
        #table {
          display: table;
          width: 200px;
          height: 100px; 
          margin: 0;
          border: 5px solid blue;
          padding: 5px;
          position: relative;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        #first {
          display: table-cell;
          border: 3px solid red;
          margin: 2px;
          width: 50px;
          height: 300px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 15%;
        }

        #second {
          display: table-cell;
          border: 3px solid red;
          margin: 2px;
          width: 50px;
          height: 300px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 55%;
        }
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div id="first"> dinesh </div>
  <div id="second"> pathak </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes It is working fine, but when I am implementing it into my project the inner elements of first and second div are overlapped\

Comment: That's because position:absolute needs to have a top and left/right property set. I used top: 0 for both, and left: 15% and left: 65%, but you may need to change them to look right in the project.